# Regular Expression for number and special characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following regex

```
^\d+(\,\.\d+)?$
```

I am trying to match the following

1. 23
2. 23.45
3. 1,156
4. 12,523
5. 1.24
6. 1.1

my expression does not work and I am looking for suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\d+([,.]\d+)?$
```

You had a **sequence** of comma and period, not a group.